# Count onsite days by serial number excluding duplications and with 2 variables

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to find a formula to count the number of visits done for a product based on serial number.

On the following example I need to count the days (start date) by serial number and by Technician, removing duplicated days (a day can have 2 service times).

Results should be as below the yellow fields, 5 onsite days for 1233457 serial (4 days by Mike and 1 day by Marcos) and 3 onsite days for 3122698 all done by Sean).

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't a code-writing service. We can help if you explain what you tried so far that isn't working, but we're not going to do it for you.

Comment: Looks like homework to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 helper columns (you can hide it later) like the following:
Your Data is in Columns A:F and Serial Number are order like your example
G is the first helper column write in G2 the following:
`=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$16,B2,$D$2:$D$16,D2,$E$2:$E$16,E2)`
and drag it down
B2:B16 Serial Number column
D2:D16 Start Date column
E2:E16 Technician column

H is the second helper column, write in H2 the following:
`=IF(G2=1,1,IF(COUNTIF($G$2:G2,">1")>1,0,1))`
and drag it down
The result is in J:K (J Serial Number, K the count you need) in K2 write:
`=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$2:$B$16=J2)*(--($H$2:$H$16=1)))`
J2 is the first Serial Number in the Result Array
and you can drag it down